# Is it possible philosophically that the entire cosmic void with one or more universe/s inside it will stop exist eternally?

Tags: consciousness, existence, universe, cosmology, infinity

As a conscious agent who suddenly appeared in this cosmic void as a child to my parents and got a consistent memory since about the age of 3;

With time I have learned of the question "why is there something rather than nothing" and that some view it as a redundant or irrational question because if there wasn't anything no one would ask it.

While there is *something* and something can't emerge if *there isn't anything to emerge from*, some have grasped our specific universe of this cosmic void as *eternal* - perhaps booming and crunching repetitively even if at some point there will be an exception so it dies in a one way heat death.

Is it possible philosophically that the entire cosmic void with one or more universe/s inside it will stop exist eternally (so, suddenly there won't be *anything* at all)?

Comment: "the entire cosmic void (with one or more universe/s inside it) will stop exist eternally?" If we have universe (matter/mind) inside, it is universe and not "cosmic void". Are you meaning "empty space" (that is part of the physical theory) or something different ? If only void, without universe, maybe also time does not exist: so, without time, what does it mean "to stop exist eternally" ?

Comment: I meant empty space but in a general sense - not necessarily that of any physics theory; just a void in which there is something and that something might be named "nothing" by some physicists such as Lawrence Krauss but I don't share this behavior of Lawrence Krauss.

Comment: "Something can't emerge if there isn't anything to emerge from" is just a loose generalization from our experience, it is not a "philosophical law", and our experience is very limited. There is nothing logically impossible either about something emerging from nothing or about it vanishing into nothing.